# HTML: How to hide list of options in the script

Tags: hide

I have 1000+ options (list of names) in html and JavaScript and would like to put them in one file which is not visible to anyone .. is it possible ? options will be updated (more options added) regularly and I would like to do it thru the file instead html and JavaScript.

Comment: Wouldn't "not visible to anyone" include yourself?

Comment: true, but I would manipulate file so I don't need to see it ... website users should be able to scroll thru all options on the webpage but if someone goes to 'inspect file' they would not be able to those options as they would be 'hidden' in the file

Answer (score 0):

use angular js that allow u to disable or enable any control in your partial page

Comment: thanks Jaydip ... have no idea how to do it but will try ... is it perhaps easy to give me a quick code for this situation:

Comment: <option value="11" class="w" style="aa">Number1</option>,
<option value="22" class="w" style="bb">Number2</option>,
<option value="33" class="w" style="cc">Number3</option>,

Comment: i.e. these 3 options are currently in the HTML but I would like to have them in the file . thank you so much